# Draw line from center of circle between two circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many nodes that is nothing but a `div` in the form of circle which will keep moving and they will be connected to each other.

Everything is working fine but the problems is the line which is connecting two nodes is not in the center and so I want to connect two nodes from the center of the circle and so if this circle keeps on moving that center position should not get changed.

This is my JS bin demo:

[JS bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/koqolulole/edit?html,js,console,output)

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: Forget about circles, create a triangle and keep circles at the very end. Handle the animation to only triangle.

Comment: @Mr_Green:But still how that line would go from center?

Comment: when the triangle is with 0 width and 0 height, all cicles will be in center. then increase the dimensions of the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use circle's width and height as starting point:

```
function connect() {
    var i, posFrom, posTo;
    for (i = 0; i < connectors.length; i++) {
        posFrom = connectors[i].from.offset();
        posTo = connectors[i].to.offset();
        drawline(posFrom.left + Math.round(connectors[i].from.width() / 2),
                 posFrom.top + Math.round(connectors[i].from.height() / 2),
                 posTo.left + Math.round(connectors[i].to.width() / 2),
                 posTo.top + Math.round(connectors[i].to.height() / 2),
                 connectors[i].from.attr("id") + "-" + connectors[i].to.attr("id")
        );
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ruhiwotewu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

[Demo 2](http://jsbin.com/nadebowani/edit?output)

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer but sometimes the lines does not remains in the center when they are in motion.can you please check it with that.your demo

Comment: @Learning: problem is in the transformation, because browser probably cannot correctly draw the line under given angle. Starting point is always correct but the end point is few pixels off.

Comment: Thank you sir.Can you please example me little bit about the changes you have done because i have tried alot and that didnt work out and you have done this just within a minutes.How ??

Comment: @Learning: angle calculation is just a minor problem. Bigger one is that that line calculation is done independently from the cyrcle movement and with lower fps, which results in a fact that it sometimes does not move with the circle and get off-center. Better see it in Demo 2. You would need to refactor whole code and render circles and lines in the same animation frame.

Comment: Awesome.Demo 2 is correct right??

Comment: I cant refactor my code because that is not possible for me because i am not good in playing with jquery

Comment: Demo 2 seem to be the best you can get with current implementation... When a circle moves from Left edge to the right one, jQuery does not trigger enough steps to smoothly render the lines, but you would need to animate them using different method to improve it. For example calculate the angle only for the newX/Y and have it animated using `jQuery.animate()` as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111002/discussion-between-learning-and-radek-pech).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this :

```css
@import "compass/css3";

li {
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 2em;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 1em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 2em;
}

li::before {
  background: black none repeat scroll 0 0;
  content: "";
  height: 0.2em;
  left: -2.7em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.9em;
  width: 2.5em;
  z-index: -1;
}



li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.active ~ li {
  background: lightblue;
}

.active ~ li::before {
  background: lightblue;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry but i need to do this with the code only but still i will upvote it because of your efforts towards helping me